# Llevar un SELECT a un NAMED QUERY

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate

Quiero realizar el siguiente `SELECT` pero en un **NAMED QUERY**, no sé si es posible.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (q1.code ||'/'|| q1.name)
  FROM (
       SELECT c.code,c.name 
         FROM USER c
       ) q1
```

Answer (score 1):

La consulta nativa que tienes puede ser perfectamente una [@NamedNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html), simplemente declárala en la entidad "USER" (si la tienes), por ejemplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "nativeSQL", query = "TU_QUERY_NATIVA",  resultClass = String.class)
public class User {
 ...contenido...
}
```

Y se ejecuta de igual forma que las demás named:

```
em.createNamedQuery("nativeSQL").getResultList();
```

La diferencia es que obtendrás un lista de la clase indicada en el resultClass de la anotación.

Si las columnas devueltas por la consulta son mas complejas y quieres mapear algo de forma mas "manual", se puede cambiar la "resultclass" por el atributo sqlResultSetMapping donde puedes indicar un [@SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) que hayas declarado en tu aplicación. 
En el propio javadoc de la anotación esta este ejemplo muy explicativo de que es un sqlResultSetMapping:

> ```
> Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
>     "SELECT o.id AS order_id, " +
>         "o.quantity AS order_quantity, " +
>         "o.item AS order_item, " +
>         "i.name AS item_name, " +
>     "FROM Order o, Item i " +
>     "WHERE (order_quantity > 25) AND (order_item = i.id)",
> "OrderResults");
>
> @SqlResultSetMapping(name="OrderResults", 
>     entities={ 
>         @EntityResult(entityClass=com.acme.Order.class, fields={
>             @FieldResult(name="id", column="order_id"),
>             @FieldResult(name="quantity", column="order_quantity"), 
>             @FieldResult(name="item", column="order_item")})},
>     columns={
>         @ColumnResult(name="item_name")}
> )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un @NamedNativeQuery la cual es una opción mas sencilla de la siguiente manera:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "USER.ejemploConsulta", query = "SELECT DISTINCT (q1.code ||'/'|| q1.name)
  FROM (
       SELECT c.code,c.name 
         FROM USER c
       ) q1")})

public class User {

}
```

pero también se puede crear como @NamedQuery: 
[Ejemplo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/CreateSubQueryWithEntities.htm)